# How to add more than 3 sheets to an excel workbook from within MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, export-to-excel

How do I add more sheets to an excel workbook from within matlab?

I set up the workbook like so (based on code I got from someone else's post in this forum):

```
    %# create Excel COM Server
    Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
    Excel.Visible = true;
    %# create new XLS file
    wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add();
    wsheet=1;
    wb.Sheets.Item(wsheet).Activate();
```

That's fine.  Then later on inside the loop I open a new sheet after so many loops:

```
    ...
    if loop==sheetlimit,
         wsheet=wsheet+1;
         wb.Sheets.Item(wsheet).Activate();
    end
```

This works up to sheet 3.  But when wsheet=4 I get this error message:

```
    ??? Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception: Invalid index.

    Error in ==> filename at 97
        wb.Sheets.Item(wsheet).Activate();
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Matlab but I would be surprised if `wb.Sheets.Item(wsheet).Activate();` is actually adding any new worksheets. Most likely it is selecting / activating each worksheet in your `wb` workbook and your default Excel template has three worksheets. Hence why it errors when it gets to more than three.

Something like this *might* add a new Excel worksheet:

```
wb.sheets.Add();
```

Comment: Yes, this will work. You can quaery the available methods of an interface like this; `methods(wb.sheets)` which gives: `Methods for class Interface.000208D7_0000_0000_C000_000000000046: Add FillAcrossSheets PrintOut addproperty events loadobj set Copy Item PrintPreview delete get release Delete Move Select deleteproperty invoke saveobj `

Answer (score 1):

Aargh - comment formatting completely messed up - I'll re-enter it as an new answer

Yes `wb.sheets.Add();` will work. You can query the available methods of an interface like this:

`methods(wb.sheets)`

which gives:

```
Methods for class Interface.000208D7_0000_0000_C000_000000000046:

Add FillAcrossSheets PrintOut addproperty events loadobj set
Copy Item PrintPreview delete get release
Delete Move Select deleteproperty invoke saveobj
```